# Exception "CASRuntimeException" while creating custom Apache UIMA CAS XML descriptor

Tags: exception, annotations, nlp, cas, uima

I am trying add additional feature "version" for storing "uima.cas.Long" type value in the UIMA CAS.

I have successfully created the XML descriptor which looks like as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<typeSystemDescription xmlns="http://uima.apache.org/resourceSpecifier">
    <types>
    <typeDescription>
            <name>CASVersion</name>
            <description/>
            <supertypeName>uima.cas.TOP</supertypeName>
            <features>
                <featureDescription>
                    <name>Version</name>
                    <description/>
                    <rangeTypeName>uima.cas.Long</rangeTypeName>
                </featureDescription>
            </features>
        </typeDescription>
    </types>
</typeSystemDescription>
```

And I generated the corresponding code using "UIMA JCasGen”.

Following classes were generated:

```
CASVersion_Type.java
CASVersion.java
```

Now, I wanted to add a version to the JCas for that I wrote following code in my java class:

```
    14: public void testAnnotation()    {
    15: JCas document = CasCreationUtils.createCas((TypeSystemDescription) null, null, null).getJCas();
    16: CASVersion version = new CASVersion(document);
    17: version.setVersion(1);
```

I am getting "CASRuntimeException" on running this code as mentioned below:

```
null
org.apache.uima.cas.CASRuntimeException: JCas type "com.example.test.CASVersion" used in Java code,  but was not declared in the XML type descriptor.
    at org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl.getTypeInit(JCasImpl.java:456)
    at org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl.getType(JCasImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.uima.jcas.cas.TOP.<init>(TOP.java:96)
    at com.example.test.CASVersion.<init>(CASVersion.java:51)
    at com.example.test.Custom.testAnnotation(Custom.java:15)
```

Code in CASVersion.java at line 51 is as follows:

```
50:  public CASVersion(JCas jcas) {
51: super(jcas);
52: readObject();   
53:  }
```

Since I am doing this for the first time I am not able to figure out how merge my custome xml descriptor to the existing XML type descriptor.

Would be great if anyone can guide me in this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This message

```
JCas type "com.example.test.CASVersion" used in Java code,  
but was not declared in the XML type descriptor.
```

means that the JCas class for your custom type is present, but UIMA is unaware of the XML descriptor describing the custom type. Assuming that you are using uimaFIT, make sure that you have set up the type system detection by creating a types.txt file pointing to your custom type's XML descriptor. For the dirty details, please refer to the [uimaFIT documentation](https://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-current/tools.uimafit.book.html#ugr.tools.uimafit.typesystem).

*Disclosure:* I am working on uimaFIT

Comment: I am using uimaFIT and have already tried both the methods mentioned for Type System Detection however I am still getting the same exception. Could it be possibe that any dependencies for uimaFIT are missing in the POM.xml and causing this issue?

Comment: Assuming you maintain the types.txt in the same project as the XML type descriptor and as the JCas classes, then uimaFIT should be able to discover the type when Java is able to find the JCas class - in that case Java would give you a "ClassNotFoundException". You can debug the uimaFIT type detection by increasing the log level for the `TypeSystemDescription` class or by setting a breakpoint in `org.apache.uima.fit.factory.TypeSystemDescriptionFactory.createTypeSystemDescription()`

Answer (score 0):

The new type was not idetified in JCas when I initialized JCas as follows:

```
    JCas document = CasCreationUtils.createCas((TypeSystemDescription) null, null, null).getJCas();
```

This was fixed by replacing it by any one of the following :

```
    //1st way
    JCas document = JCasFactory.createJCas();

    //2nd way
    TypeSystemDescription tsd = TypeSystemDescriptionFactory.createTypeSystemDescription();
    JCas document = CasCreationUtils.createCas(tsd, null, null).getJCas();
```